# Weird error when using Send to Unreal Plugin

Tags: python, add-on, unreal-engine

I'm trying to use the SendToUE plugin but it's throwing up a config error. Has anyone had experience with this or know how to resolve it?

Running the latest version of the plugin in 3.3 and 3.4 with the same results.

```
<Fault 1: "<class 'configparser.NoOptionError'>:No option 'r.skincache.compileshaders' in section: '/Script/Engine.RendererSettings'">
```

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/mxr2es/send_to_unreal_blender_addon_dead/

Comment: This is a slightly different issue (you need to have the correct plugins and remote execution enabled).

Answer (score 1):

To make it work check the *Support Compute Skin Cache* option in Unreal's rendering settings.